# Excel - Copy cell if worksheet is present

Tags: excel, vba

What I intent to accomplish is the following:

I need to copy and paste the value of a cell from a different/another worksheet, the other worksheet may or may not exist, if there is no worksheet I just need a "n/a" in the target cell, and if it does exist I need the value. 
I need this to happen without a click on a button/macro, nut maybe on a Event Change
Thank you

Comment: Please show the code you've already attempted.  Note that you can record a macro, perform the action you want done in the case that the sheet exists.  Once you've assembled the basic code we can help you with your conditions.

Comment: *[b]ut maybe on a Event Change* If you can be more specific and tell us what you have tried and is not working, that would help us help a lot more! See [mcve].

Comment: I did get to have an average of 3 worksheets using:
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(January!I7, INDIRECT("'January1'!I7"), INDIRECT("January2!I7")),
 IFERROR(AVERAGE(January!I7,INDIRECT("'January1'!I7")),
 January!I7))
but cannot get it to work just for individual worksheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a formula, not macro. Does this work for you?

```
= IFERROR(INDIRECT("'<sheet name>'!<cell name>"),"n/a")
```

For example,

```
= IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A1"),"n/a")
```

See example below, demonstrates formula works.

[image]

**NOTE** The only time that the formula would return `n/a` when the sheet exists is if the cell it is referencing, itself, contains an error value. See example below.

[image]

Comment: This is not a macro

Comment: @n8. True, I thought I would give a pure formula approach to see if that was sufficient.

Comment: @n8. - This appears to fulfill all of the OP's vague requirements and since the OP has offered nothing more than a phishing expedition, I would consider this an apprpriate response to an *XY problem*.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 - maybe `worksheets("sheet1").range("a1").formula = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(""'Sheet1'!A1""), ""n/a"")"`

Comment: True enough.  I would have spent more time on it but then I tend to bias against newer users who ask a question and disappear forever.

Comment: Hello, I did not disappear, and I thank you for your responses. Using the formula alone gives me an "n/a" regardless of the value of the '<sheet name>'!<cell name>

Comment: I am working on a workbook (dashboard) that will gather information out of worksheets to show progress or lack of progress, each worksheet represents an inspection report. Inspections are done at a minimum once a month but depending on the score, it may have to be done 1 or 2 more times. So when I say the worksheet may or may not exists it is because of that. Worksheets are crated by a macro and they have a pre-assigned name (May1, May2). and the position of the cell which contains the value is I7. I want the dashboard to show me at a glance the score for the particular inspection if exists.

Comment: @RHC002 The formula works. Please see my edited answer to demonstrate a basic example of it working. What exact formula are you using? I would think that the formula you use would be something like this formula: `= IFERROR(INDIRECT("'May1'!I7"),"n/a")` based on your comment here.

Comment: You are correct, it did work, thank you for your help